# DIV half of proper size

Tags: html, css

I have a series of stacked `<div>` tags. They are all supposed to be the same size—half of the window; however, only the first in the series is the correct size.

**CSS**

```
.left {
    padding: 5% 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #364d9d;
    position: absolute;
}
.right {
    padding: 5% 10%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2f463d;
    position: absolute;
}
#yes {
    z-index: 6;
}
#no {
    z-index: 5;
}
#violence {
    z-index: 4;
}
#peace {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left" id="yes">
    <p>Yes</p>
</div>
<div class="right" id="no">
    <p>No</p>
</div>
<div class="left" id="violence">
    <p>Violence</p>
</div>
<div class="right" id="peace">
    <p>Peace</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djo2L8mn/6/)

[JSFiddle with original width: 50% that caused an overlap](https://jsfiddle.net/djo2L8mn/8/)

I've tried setting the DIVs to position: relative, and floating and clearing them. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you want them all stacked on top of eachother so that the ones underneath the top div don't show or do you want to display them inline two at a time?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking for. When you say 'half the window' do you mean horizontal or vertical?

Comment: Ah. Nowhere in your code to you tell the `div` to be 50% wide. See Joost's answer below

Comment: He did show 50% wide in the second fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding on your `<div>`s have impact on their size. Remove the padding from your `<div>`s and move them to their children. You could also add another `<div>` instead of applying the padding to the `<p>`.

```css
.right, .left  {
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.right p, .left p {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djo2L8mn/11/